# If $GCD(a,b)=1$, then $GCD((a+b)^m , (a-b)^m )$ is at most $2^m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I'm stuck for a few days in the following problem:

If $GCD(a,b)=1$, then $GCD((a+b)^m , (a-b)^m )$ is at most $2^m$.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: $GCD(a+b, a-b)$ is either $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Separate the proof into two pieces. First consider the case $m=1$. Second, assuming the claim holds for $m=1$, proof it holds for all $m$.